# How to cast a boolean value to string by using BIRT

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

I have a query like that :

```
select myId, myName, myBoolean from myTable
```

I hope to get a BIRT table :

```
if myBoolen is true, print `smart` else print `sorry you're ...`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select myId, 
       myName, 
       case when myBoolean = 1 
            then 'smart' 
            else 'sorry ...'  
       end
from myTable
```